# How to define Assetic resources in Symfony 2 yml or xml configuration file?

Tags: symfony1, asset-management

Can you define assetic resource in configuration file (yml/xml)?

Lets take jquery as example. I would like to have configuration like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
  resources:
     jquery: 
        latest: "app/Resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"
        1_6_2: "app/Resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"
        1_5: "app/Resources/js/jquery-1.5.js"
```

And to be able to access this resource from any template in my application something like this:

```
{% javascripts 'jquery.latest' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

What is a proper way to do this?

And another thing. How do I reference path app/Resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js in twig template?

```
{% javascripts 'app/Resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This does not work. Can you do this at all? What resources I can place in app/Resources and how do I access them in my templates? Where it is documented?

Right now Symfony 2 is really lacking in documentation...

Comment: Here you can find answer to your first question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840936/2880092

Answer (score 4):

The path to define resources in your app/Resources folder must defined with a trailing: "../"

```
{% javascripts 
  "../app/Resources/js/qtip.jquery.js"
  "../app/Resources/js/layout.js"
  "@HomeBundle/Resources/js/*"  
%}
```

Not entirely sure how to help you on your first question, though, but hopefully this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something along the lines of

```
{% javascripts '@NameOfYourBundle/path/from/bundle/root/to/jquery-1.6.2.js' %}
```

Comment: That works for bundle resources, but not for global resources that reside in /app/Resources directory. Maybe this is by design, just to keep things separated. But you can reference global template app/Resources/view/base.html.twig like this in twig: {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}. So why it should not work for css in {% stylesheets %} ?