# With Assetic / Twig / Symfony2, can I define front end libraries?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I'm using Symfony2, with Assetic and Twig. I have various frontend libraries - Backbone, jQuery, jQuery UI, and Bootstrap. Both Bootstrap and jQuery UI include CSS and JS files.

Is there a way that I can define the resources they need to include (including dependencies), and then in Twig / Assetic just include all those resources in one tag? What I'd look to have is something like:

```
// config.yml <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
assetic:
  resources:
    jquery:
      js: /filepath/to/jquery.js
    jquery_ui:
      dependencies: jquery
      css: /filepath/to/jqueryui.css
      js: /filepath/to/jqueryui.js
    less:
      js: /filepath/to/less.js
    bootstrap:
      dependencies: { less, jquery }
      js: /filepath/to/bootstrap.js
      css: /filepath/to/bootstrap.css
    backbone:
      dependencies: { jquery }
      js: { /filepath/to/underscore.js, /filepath/to/backbone.js }

// view.html.twig
{% use jquery_ui %}
{% use bootstrap %} 

// outputs all js and css for jQuery, jQueryUI, Less, Backbone, and Bootstrap
```

I found a couple of related questions:

- [How to define Assetic resources in Symfony 2 yml or xml configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922759/how-to-define-assetic-resources-in-symfony-2-yml-or-xml-configuration-file)
- [Symfony2 Assetic + Twig Template JavaScript Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769269/symfony2-assetic-twig-template-javascript-inheritance)

but neither seems to involve defining the resources in config.yml. Instead, they define them in `base.html.twig` but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

I tried using the `use` tag in Twig, by defining a template called 'jquery_ui' and using `{% stylesheets %}` and `{% javascripts %}` in that block and then in `base.html.twig` putting `{% use "jquery-ui.html" %}`. However, `use` won't import the template because it has a body.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although there is indeed support for defining front-end libraries, there is unfortunately no support for dependency resolving. You must also define your CSS and JavaScript separately.

What I have been doing, is creating a separate file in `/app/config/` called `assets.yml` and including it in the main configuration to keep things clean.

```
assetic:
    assets:
        jquery:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.js'
        my_lib:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/my-custom-lib.js'
                - ...
```

Note that ´%kernel.root_dir%´ resolves to the `app` directory by default in Symfony2. You may now use the assets in your Twig templates.

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@jquery' '@my_lib' output="js/jquery.js" %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

The same could be done for CSS files. The example also demonstrates why it's not possible to define CSS and JavaScript as a single asset.

Comment: I recommend to use a `package.json` in the root of the project, and a keep notes of how to rebuild the workspace in files at the root of the project.  Sometimes I also add scripts in the `app/` directory.

Comment: How could I use package.json for that?

Comment: This looks brilliant.  However, I have a question about what happens when you extend the template's `{% block javascripts %}`?. Presumably you need to use the `{{ parent() }}` placeholder in the child. Would it be better to define the `{% javascripts %}` tag outside of the `{% block javascripts %}` to avoid having to type this each time?  Can the child-template also include a `{% javascripts %}` tag?  Is Assetic still clever enough to compile only one css/js file? Or does it compile one for the 'global' site, and another for the extending bundle?

Comment: @cartbeforehorse Well yeah. you'd have to use `{{ parent() }}` if you're extending a template and want to add some more scripts to the page. Assetic doesn't compile the parent scripts and scripts in the extended template to a single file and that in my opinion is good - the client will cache common scripts and download unique scripts for a page. Alternatively you could define a separate block if you don't want to write `{{ parent() }}` every time.

Comment: @gilden I should have done more testing first before asking my questions. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I didn't fully understand the `{% javascripts %}` tag. I did a bit more research, and understand a bit better now. Thanks for your reply though -- it confirms everything else I found too, which is reassuring.

Comment: @gilden How does the javascripts tag know how to use `@jquery` and `@my_lib` in this example? Where is this documented?

Comment: @BadHorsie it's in [one of the Symfony cookbooks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets). If you're wondering how it's wired together with Assetic, then that's done in [AsseticBundle](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/v2.5.0/DependencyInjection/AsseticExtension.php#L59) during container building.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to put them in appropriate directories in the web/ directory as this is the root of your site that is served for all your Symfony bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Cartero, which allows you to define "asset bundles", including dependencies, and then include those bundles in your page.

https://github.com/rotundasoftware/cartero

You would need to write a Symfony2 Hook, but that wouldn't be too difficult.