# Assetic Add file located in app/Resources/js

Tags: symfony, assetic

I am creating a bundle that requires a 3rd party js file. According to the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors

Bundles should not contain 3rd party code. Since the bundle is only used in one part of the site I dont want to include it in my base template file - I want to call it from the twig file, but I am running into a problem there.

All of the demos for including js seem to reference a bundle name, but I have placed my js in app/Resources/public/js

If I use:

```
{% javascripts 
    "public/js/jquery.fileupload.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

It looks in the web directory. Is there any way to use the app dir where all of my other js files live? I'm trying to follow best practices where feasible, but I would really like to keep my js in one place for simplicity, thanks for reading!

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192568/symfony2-how-to-share-js-libs-and-css-between-bundles

Comment: nope I get a 500 response. I think it's mangling the path something like ../app/..web/..app which isnt finding the file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by symlinking the `Public` directory in `app/Resources`. It's kinda messy but it should work.

On *nix, you could run:

```
cd ROOT_TO_YOUR_PROJECT/web/bundles
ln -s ../../app/Resources/Public common
```

Basically, you are creating `common` symlink that points to you `Public` directory.

Then:

```
{% javascripts 
    "bundles/common/js/jquery.fileupload.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems kinda like a workaround. Maybe the fact the there isnt any easy way to do this means that I should just a create a Layout or Template Bundle and house all of my assets there. Then I can access those files the 'Symfony' way. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

This sounds related to a bug in Symfony's assetic. When you run `app/console assetic:dump` it doesn't base itself in the web folder, it uses the current folder. See: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/202