# Sharing stylesheets between bundles in Symfony2

Tags: css, symfony

Is it possible to put a stylesheet in a centralised location? I think putting a css file in the web/bundles/BundleName/css directory is not a good idea, if it is a global stylesheet that I wish for all bundles to use (ie. by including it in base.html.twig).

What do I need to do in order to put a stylesheet in a location where it can logically and easily be used by different bundles?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put it in

```
/web/css
```

and link them like this without assetic

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
```

The negative sideeffect is, that you can not use the benefits of assetic like minification or uglification.

---

The more correct solution would be to place them in `app/Resources/Public` which is described here **[Symfony2: How to share js libs and css between bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192568/symfony2-how-to-share-js-libs-and-css-between-bundles)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I want to put the css files in app/Resources/public/css/ (to maintain the same sort of structure that exists for base.html.twig) how will I reference those css files from base.html.twig?

Comment: @b85411 it is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192568/symfony2-how-to-share-js-libs-and-css-between-bundles