# Include jQuery into Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I am new in Symfony2 framework and not fully understand how to work with javascripts and how to include theirs in the best way.

What I need: to include jQuery script to each page.

What I have: I have common layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Where jquery.js should be placed. What about **web/bundles/jquery**? Or there are some special official jquery bundles? Should I use asset() and how?

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830129#answer-10840936). You shouldn't put vendor libs to your own bundles. Use 'app/Resources/...' for any front-end libs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your jquery.min.js is placed under
`src/Acme/FooBundle/Resources/public/js/`

You can use either

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/acmefoo/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
{% javascripts
    '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Into your twig template.

Make sure you installed the assets afterwards or run this command

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to include jQuery in a Symfony project. You can:

### 1. Install jQuery with a front-end package manager (Bower)

The [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/frontend/bower.html) states:

> **Bower** is a dependency management tool for front-end dependencies, like Bootstrap or **jQuery**.

If Bower isn't already installed, you can install it globally with npm (require node):

```
npm install -g bower
```

According to the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors):

> A bundle should not embed third-party libraries written in JavaScript, CSS or any other language.

So, we store jQuery directly in the `web/` directory which is publicly accessible. To tell Bower where to install packages, create a *.bowerrc* file in your Symfony project root with this content:

```
{
    "directory": "web/assets/vendor/"
}
```

Execute `bower init` in your project root to create *bower.json* which will define installed packages. Type enter for every question to answer the default value (select 'globals' for the type of modules).

Bower is ready to install jQuery in your project:

```
bower install --save jquery
```

Now you can include jQuery in your template:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

*Currently Bower does not have a ["lock" feature like on Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-with-composer-lock). That's why you should probably commit the assets downloaded by Bower instead of adding the directory to your .gitignore file. This will probably change in the future: [bower/bower#1748](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1748).*

### 2. Install jQuery with Composer

Even if Composer is a dependency manager for PHP, you can also use it to install jQuery.

To make Composer able to install components like [components/jquery](https://packagist.org/packages/components/jquery), you need first to add the [component-installer](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer):

```
composer require robloach/component-installer
```

Then modify your *composer.json* file to include:

```
"require": {
    "components/jquery": "3.1.1"
},
"config": {
    "component-dir": "web/assets/vendor"
},
```

and execute `composer install`. This will install jQuery in the `web/assets/vendor` directory.

You can then include jQuery in your template:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

### 3. Include jQuery from a CDN

For example with Google CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

About advantages and disadvantages to using a CDN, I suggest you to read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery).

### In all cases:

To make sure your scripts (which require jQuery) will work, jQuery has to be loaded first. So, depending on your page loading requirements, you should either:

- include jQuery just before you need it, or
- include it in the `<HEAD>`, or
- use [defer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) in your scripts

Comment: The composer way does not install the folder in the component-dir path. It steel install it in the vendor folder

Comment: It installs well jQuery in `web/assets/vendor`, I just tested it. Pay attention to update _composer.json_ before executing `composer install`. If `composer install`  installs nothing, use `composer update` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of purity. Of course the `<script>` tags should be closed, so the correct code snippets are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/acmefoo/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

and

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Otherwise the whole content of the page would be treated as the content of the `script` tag and would appear blank.

Comment: For unknown reasons, using html-legal singleton (self-closing) script tag breaks the sf-toolbar (on chrome at least).

 bad:
              
`<script src="{{ asset('bundles/jquery/jquery.js') }}" />`

Using the empty-but-closed tag works.

Good:

`<script src="{{ asset('bundles/jquery/jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: @dman self closing script tags are not valid HTML as per W3C HTML4 / 5 or XHTML specifications. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1 It must contain both start and end tags.

Answer (score 0):

For implementation with a composer package, navigate to your symfony package and run the following commands.

**Download Vendor Package:**

The package you choose is up to you, I am using a popular package (bmatzner/jquery-bundle) for this example.

`php composer.phar require bmatzner/jquery-bundle:2.*` for jQuery 2.x

or

`php composer.phar require bmatzner/jquery-bundle:1.*` for jQuery 1.x

**Add The Bundle to your AppKernel:**

```php
/* /app/AppKernel.php */

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Bmatzner\JQueryBundle\BmatznerJQueryBundle(),
    ///...
```

**Install Assets:**

`php bin/console assets:install --symlink web`

**To include in template:**

```
<!-- /app/Resources/views/base.html.twig -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjquery/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Clear Cache:**

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```