# How to Install Jquery in Symfony 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Is there a step by step guide into installing jQuery and bootstrap in Symfony3? I have only found outdated Symfony2 guides till now.

Comment: You can include jQuery in a Symfony 3 project as same as you do with Symfony 2. I suggest you to read how to do it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41324944/1941316).

Answer (score -1):

You could manually download them inside the web folder under their respective folders:

```
web/bootstrap
web/jquery
```

and include them in your (twig) templates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```