# JQuery: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I use Symfony 5, but I can not make an AJAX call because it says that "$.ajax is not a function". I installed jQuery using **composer require components/jquery** and it does not work. I took the jquery directory from /vendor/components and I pasted it into the public directory, into a directory called "assets" and then I tried to include it with:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/jquery/jquery.js')}}">`

But nothing works. The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let id = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/getBuildingDetails",
                type: "GET",
                data: id,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Something went wrong");
                }
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

I searched the error and the only thing was to change jquery.slim.min.js to jquery.min.js, but I already use jquery.min.js(at least I am trying to use it...). I tried with the cdn, but nothing works. I am new, I don't have experience... Do you have a video or an article that can help me? Thank you!

Comment: try to inspect element the existing error page via your browser (F12), then you will see the jquery url, right click on that, and press open link on new tab, you will see where the link goes

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it but I don't understand why $.ajax is not recognized as a function... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Data should be an object. Try " data: {id : id} "

Comment: It does not work. I also have an warning: "jQuery.Deferred exception: $.ajax is not a function".

Comment: Does this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007911/include-jquery-into-symfony2

Comment: Thank you! I solved it. I use Bootstrap and some components require jquery.slim.min.js and there was the problem. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Previously people have experienced issues with self closing tags...try below:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery/jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```